# notifyListeners() does not return data to UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I am new to flutter and need some help please
I have this screen with GoogleMaps (simplified for here):

```
class OrderDetailsScreen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrderDetailsScreen1({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrderDetailsScreen1State createState() => _OrderDetailsScreen1State();
}

class _OrderDetailsScreen1State extends State<OrderDetailsScreen1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final googleMapsNotifier =
        Provider.of<GoogleMapsNotifier>(context, listen: true);

    double latitude = -33.75;
    double longitude = -70.67;

    if (googleMapsNotifier.currentLocation != null) {
      latitude = googleMapsNotifier.currentLocation!.latitude;
      longitude = googleMapsNotifier.currentLocation!.longitude;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          child: GoogleMap(
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
              zoom: 14,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I push this screen from the previous one like this

```
onTap: () {
   Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Provider<GoogleMapsNotifier>(
              create: (_) => GoogleMapsNotifier(),
              child: OrderDetailsScreen1(
        ),
     )));
},
```

And I have a class `GoogleMapsNotifier with ChangeNotifier` like this

```
class GoogleMapsNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  final geolocatorService = GeolocatorService();

  Position? currentLocation;

  GoogleMapsNotifier() {
    setCurrentLocation();
  }

  setCurrentLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await geolocatorService.determinePosition();
    print(currentLocation!.latitude);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Inside `setCurrentLocation()` of `GoogleMapsNotifier` it get `currentLocation` fine and prints it fine. But  `notifyListeners()` does not pass data back to the UI (OrderDetailsScreen1). It does not react and I have no errors in the Console. Where is the mistake?

UPD: I tried to change the MaterialPageRoute to the below and it didn't help

```
onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Provider.value(                                     
               value: Provider.of<GoogleMapsNotifier>(context),
               child: OrderDetailsScreen1(),
         )));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the existing provider

```
onTap: () {
   Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Provider.value(
              value: googleMapsNotifier,
              child: OrderDetailsScreen1(
        ),
     )));
},
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't change anything. Please see the upd of the main post how I set it.

Comment: @MarchukAnton, check Devtools if your googleMapsNotifierProvider is on OrderDetailScreen1 tree. And remember Provider create, create a new instance of that provider. it wont use the existing provider which has changes on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your Ui widget with Consumer of specific provider. So it will be update state of your Ui through provider.